# Spring SocketException cause JSON Parse Error

Tags: json, spring, parsing, io, socketexception

I have a Spring Boot Application, and use restTemplate to send http request to other services, problem is from time to time(not frequent) I got this Json parse exception. Retry will be successful.

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Connection reset; 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Connection reset (through reference chain: Response["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[23])\n
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:240)\n   
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225)\n   
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:96)\n    
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:934)\n 
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:918)\n
```

It seems like a simple Json parse error, however I notice that in the call stack there is another cause

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset\n 
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)\n    
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)\n
```

My question will this IO exception cause Json parse error.
My guess is because of TCP issue, part of Json data is lost, then Json cannot be properly parsed by the ObjectMapper.